# Disable controller endpoints using Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Suppose I have a Spring MVC Controller as below:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/doSomething", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody JSONObject doSomething() {
    //...
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/doOtherThing", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody JSONObject doOtherThing() {
    //...
    }
}
```

Is there a way, using Spring XML files ou some other configuration, to disable just one endpoint of this controller? For example, disable /doSomething and keep /doOtherThing enabled?

The reason I'm asking is because I need to add two different versions of a component (jar), that has a controller with several endpoints, but I need to disable doSomething in jar 1.0 and use doSomething on jar 2.0.

Comment: Disable and do what? If  they hit `/doSomething`, return 404?

Comment: What exactly do you want Spring to do when client posts using `doSomething()`?

Comment: You can create an interceptor and check for the URL and throw error (404??) conditionally. But curious to know why do u want to turn off the endpoint?

Comment: I've edited the question to explain the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an filter... 
configure an object where every instance is a restricted mapping present in the controllers.. now say you want to prevent "www.someaddress.com/yourapp/finalMapping", add an object of type  DisabledUrl  with the id field being the full mapping. Define a repository or a mean for you to interrogate such table, and lo' and behold, you can at runtime restrict access to resource.. a better way would be to persist in eh-cache the list of "disabled" mapping and avoid querying the database for every request, but let's say that this work as a rough solution..

```
            @Component(value = "yourNiceFilter")
            public class YourNiceFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

            @Autowired
            private DisabledUrlRepository disabledUrlRepository;

                private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YourNiceFilter.class);

                @Override
                protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                                throws ServletException, IOException {
                    //String[] path = request.getRequestURL().toString().split("/");

                                if (letPagePass(request.getRequestURL().toString()) == false)
                                {   
                                    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/your/courtesy/page/requestMapper");
                                    return;
                                }
                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

                }

                public boolean letPagePass(String url)
                {
                String mappedPage = null;
                //do something and extract the identifier of the "mapping"
                if (mappedPage != null)
                {
                    if (disabledUrlRepository.findOne(mappedPage) != null);
                    {
                    return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
                }
```